Proving an upper bound of the resolvant operator
Given a self-adjoint operator $A$ in a Hilbert space, I need to prove $$\|(A-zI)^{-1} \|\leq \frac{1}{\text{Im}z}, z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}.$$ Can you provide some hint or a solution proposal?

Is this in a Hilbert space?

Yes, it is about an operator in a Hilbert space.

$$|\langle (A-zI)x, x \rangle|=|\langle Ax, x \rangle-z \langle x, x \rangle|\ge Im \, z \langle x, x \rangle$$ Put $y=(A-zI)x$. You get: $$|\langle(A-zI)^{-1} y, y \rangle|\ge Im \, z \|(A-zI)^{-1} y\|^{2}$$ Hence: $$Im \, z \|(A-zI)^{-1} y\|^{2} \le \|(A-zI)^{-1} y\|\|y\|$$ Or: $$Im \, z \|(A-zI)^{-1} y\| \le \|y\|$$ Which gives: $$\|(A-zI)^{-1}\|\le \frac 1 {Im \, z}$$

Thanks. How do you get the very first inequality on the first line ?

$|w|\ge Im , w$ for any complex number $w$. Note that $\langle Ax, x \rangle$ is a real number, so its imaginary part is $0$.  @user996159

Thats correct, but how do I see that the LHS is precisely $|w<x,x>|$ ?

Imaginary part of $\langle Ax, x \rangle -z\langle x, x \rangle$ equals $0-(Im, z) \langle x, x \rangle$ because $\langle Ax, x \rangle$ and $\langle x, x \rangle$ are both real numbers.  @user996159
